# How to add the suffix to the particular data in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have maintained a worksheet which contains the parameters of a particular product.

Here when i click ADD button all the contents of the CONTROL POWER TRANSFORMERS should get copied and it should get pasted below.

Here i am successful in copying the entire product details and pasting below using the vba code as mentioned below:

```
Dim WbEPC As Workbook, _
WbCPT As Workbook, _
WsEPC As Worksheet, _
WsCPT As Worksheet, _
FirstAddress As String, _
WriteRow As Long, _
cF As Range, _
num As String

Set WbEPC = Workbooks("EPC 1.xlsm")
Set WbCPT = Workbooks("Control Power Transformers.xlsm")
Set WsEPC = WbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WsCPT = WbCPT.Sheets("Sheet1")


Dim b As Object, RowNumber As Integer
Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton21")
With b.TopLeftCell
    RowNumber = .Row
End With


 Rows(RowNumber + 1 & ":" & RowNumber + 1).Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

With WsEPC
.Activate
With .Range("A1:A10000")

Set cF = .Find(what:="CTPT", _
    lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            num = cF.Address

            WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(-1, 0), cF.Offset(3, 3).End(xlDown)).Copy

            WsEPC.Range("A" & RowNumber + 1).Select


                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With
 End With

 MsgBox " Successfully added the product to EPC"
```

The above code is successfully copying the above product details below as shown below

[image]

Here "CTPT1" is the unique product id given to the product CONTROL POWER TRANSFORMERS and the same id is copying when i  click ADD, instead of copying CTPT1 as shown in the figure(A22) i want it to automatically make itself to "CTPT2" when Add button is clicked, like wise if the add button is again clicked it should become "CTPT3" and so on.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this automatic generation of the unique id using excel VBA.  Any help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
Dim WbEPC As Workbook, _
    WbCPT As Workbook, _
    WsEPC As Worksheet, _
    WsCPT As Worksheet, _
    StringToSearch As String, _
    ButtonRow As Long, _
    WriteRow As Long, _
    cF As Range


Set WbEPC = Workbooks("EPC 1.xlsm")
Set WbCPT = Workbooks("Control Power Transformers.xlsm")
Set WsEPC = WbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WsCPT = WbCPT.Sheets("Sheet1")
StringToSearch = "CTPT"

With WsEPC
    .Activate
    ButtonRow = .Shapes("CommandButton21").TopLeftCell.Row
    .Rows(ButtonRow + 1 & ":" & ButtonRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
                                                    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    With .Columns(1)
        Set cF = .Find(what:=StringToSearch, _
                        lookat:=xlPart, _
                        searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                        searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)
        WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(-1, 0), cF.Offset(3, 3).End(xlDown)).Copy
        WriteRow = WsEPC.Range("B" & WsEPC.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
        WsEPC.Range("A" & WriteRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        cF.Value = CStr(StringToSearch & CLng(Replace(cF.Value, StringToSearch, vbNullString)) + 1)
    End With
End With

MsgBox " Successfully added the product to EPC"
```

Comment: Nope, there is a type mis-match error at cF.Value statement.

Comment: You mean on the `cF.Value = CStr(...` line? @KarthikPB : Did you change `CTPT` to `CTPT1`? Because I only get the error when there is no number!

Comment: Now its working, but the thing is its working in reverse direction, i mean the copied product unique  id incrementing, i want the pasted product unique id to get incremented, i'll see whether it can be achieved by doing some fine tuning in code which you have given.

Comment: You mean that you want the *counter* to decrease? Because the code actually increment (see the `+1` at the end of `cF.Value = CStr(...` line) it, put `CTPT1` and it'll become `CTPT2`, then `CTPT3`; and so on... So I don't know what is the issue here...

Comment: This is the format which i am expecting mate
    CTPT1  --- Original Data
    CTPT2  ---- Copied Data
    CTPT3 ----Copied Data
 and so on

But now its like(If we click ADD 2 times)

CTPT 3 --- Copied Data
CTPT2 ---- Copied Data
CTPT1 ---- Original Data

Original Data is Pushed Down as and when the button is clicked but i need the copied data to be pushed down instead of original data

Comment: And that is what the code actually does... At least for me, but it most certainly canNOT decrements the variable, so what is your input/output??

Comment: Mkay, so it is just the insert line which is not good, let me take a closer look... The issue here is that you work with the button's row (and the button doesn't move...) to insert the data, but actually, you want it at the end of the sheet's data? is that it?